# Detecting Google Maps streetview mode

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How do I know when the google map is in streetview mode or roadmap mode? Is there an event that gets fired? I tried looking through the docs, and there doesn't seem to be anything. Am I missing something?

When the user switches into streetview mode, I want the UI to change, but I don't know which event to bind to.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Detect the `visible_changed` event on the `StreetViewPanorama` associated with your `Map` object. You can get the panorama from the map by calling its `getStreetView()` method and bind the handler to that object's event. You will have to test the `StreetViewPanorama`'s visibility by calling its `getVisible()` method.

For instance:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("theMap"), {streetViewControl: true});

var thePanorama = map.getStreetView();

google.maps.event.addListener(thePanorama, 'visible_changed', function() {

    if (thePanorama.getVisible()) {

        // Display your street view visible UI

    } else {

        // Display your original UI

    }

});
```

See the events section of the [StreetViewPanorama Object Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#StreetViewPanorama) for more events you can listen for on this object.

Comment: Yea I managed to figure it out late last night, thanks though :D

Comment: @userinev Doh, I posted this within 15 minutes of your asking, hehe. Too bad you didn't check back sooner. :[

Comment: For some reason the event is fired more than once on each enter/exit change for me.

Comment: @GerardReches Are you certain the event is fired twice, or is it possible you've attached your handler multiple times?

Comment: @lthibodeaux I'm sure, I attached the handler inside a function, and this function is only called once. At map load the event is fired once, when I enter to street view is fired two times, and when I exit street view is fired once. I don't know why is fired two times only when I enter to Street View.