# What event can I latch onto when Google Maps goes to street view?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, dom-events, google-street-view

I want to trigger a Javascript function whenever a user switches from overhead view to street view in a Google Map (js API v3).

Ideally, I could find a map-level event onto which I could hang a listener -- something that fires when the map (the object for which is, conveniently called `map` in my code) goes from overhead view to street view.

I have tried `maptypeid_changed` and `zoom_changed`, with no success. (My function runs fine when the overhead view's type or zoom is changed, but the transition to street view appears not to trigger either event.) Does anyone know if there's a map-level (as opposed to panorama-level) event I can listen for? If so, which event?

Failing that, is there a property of `map.streetView` that I could simply check every 30 seconds to see whether the user is viewing Street View? I had thought that looking at the value of boolean `map.streetView.visible` might do the trick, but it looks like this just indicates whether the current area has data.

Comment: Absolutely. I'll officially answer the question so it closes, unless there's a more kosher way to close it. I look for dupes, but even the best of us miss them sometimes. Thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 0):

This question was actually already answered, as per Duncan_m.

See [Detecting Google Maps streetview mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7251738/detecting-google-maps-streetview-mode)

Comment: Hmm ... looks like that didn't work the way I wanted it to. This question is apparently going to stay open for another couple days, even if I want it to quietly die. Live and learn!