# Google Maps API - Fire event when Street View enable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

How can i check when user open street view in Google Maps?

i.e. i have standard map, user take this little boy in right corner and open street view, then i want to know he did it and do sth.

ps. Some text...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you set an event listener on visible_changed. See: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview for the events and this answer:
[Detecting Google Maps streetview mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7251738/detecting-google-maps-streetview-mode)