# Google Map API Street View controls?

Tags: javascript, api, google-street-view

I couldn't figure out how to change/hide Street View controls [in scenario](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple) where **there's a map by default and you drag "little guy" to road**.

This is the piece of code about my options:

```
    function initMap() {

        var mapOptions = { 
            center: new google.maps.LatLng( <?php echo $latitude . ',' . $longitude; ?>),
            zoom: 12,
            disableDefaultUI: true,
            backgroundColor: 'white',
            streetViewControl: true
            };
// I have markers & other stuff in here, it's properly closed function!
```

I found reference for Street View controls **only when it's Street View by default**, here's a [code example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-controls) from Google Developers:

```
function initPano() {
  // Note: constructed panorama objects have visible: true
  // set by default.
  var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
      document.getElementById('map'), {
        position: {lat: 42.345573, lng: -71.098326},
        addressControlOptions: {
          position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER
        },
        linksControl: false,
        panControl: false,
        zoomControlOptions: {
          style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
        },
        enableCloseButton: false
  });
}
```

**How to add Street View UI options if default view is map and you can drag Street View "guy" to map?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this answer to see if it helps. I think you need to listen for the streetview becoming visible and then hide the controls using streetViewControl = false etc.

[Detecting Google Maps streetview mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7251738/detecting-google-maps-streetview-mode)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Keep up the good work! Cheers!